# ActiveAndroid optimization relative tables

Tags: android, performance, optimization, database-design, activeandroid

I have the app that uses `ActiveAndroid ORM` and I need to save list of models with inner list and objects, that looks like this:

```
public class MyModel extends Model{
 @Expose
 @SerializedName(Columns.COLUMN_CREATED_AT)
 @Column(name=Columns.COLUMN_CREATED_AT)
 private Date createdAt;
  .... and other fields

 @Expose
 @SerializedName(Columns.User)
 public User users;
 .... another objects
}
```

so, the current logic that saves `List<MyModel>` do next:

1) makes all update in `ActiveAndroid.beginTransaction() / ActiveAndroid.endTransaction();` block

2) for each `MyModel` `user model` retrieves from db, updates and saves

3) each `MyModel` retrieves from db, updates and saves

so the whole process takes about 7-9 seconds.

As the `user` (and others inner objects) can be the same in different `MyModel` objects i've do the next:

in the loop that saves `MyModel` I gets the `users` and put it to `HashMap`, so i got the list of *unique users* and saves it after `MyModel` updates. (but the same transaction). now it saves data for 3-4 seconds.

BUT, looks `ActiveAndroid` makes some references between `MyModel` and `User` table, so when i tried to remove users from table i got an exception:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

so, how can i deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `ActiveAndroid` is not supported for last 3 years... the solution for me was to migrate to another `orm`.
one more reason against `ActiveAndroid` - [is slower than others](https://github.com/Rexee/AndroidDatabaseLibraryComparison)